# Entity Framework 6.4.4 is unable to generate Entity Classes from EDMX through 'Run Custom Tool' option. Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, edmx

I have created two tabled in the database and I was able to add them to the Edmx by updating the model from the database, however, the entity classes for the tables that should've been generated are missing.

What I have tried?

I have tried clicking `Run Customer Tool` option by right clicking the the Edmx file but it did not produce any entity class which I was expecting. Moreover, the `Run Custom Tool` is only appearing when I right click the Edmx file and it is missing when I right click the `.tt` one.

On some answers I read that there was an open bug which is now fixed and so I have updated the `Visual Studio` to the latest version which is `17.7.4`, however, it did not make any difference.

I am using `EntityFramework 6.4.4` and I do not want to manually write the entity file as all current entity files were automatically generated.

The Edmx Model is successfully updated from the database and I can see the table in the design view, but there are no entity classes.

```
Visual Studio 17.7.4
Entity Framework 6.4.4
.NET Framework 4.8.1
```

What can I do to fix it this issue?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the entity classes don't exist? They are nested in the solution explorer under other files, so you may need to hunt around for them. Do you have a DbContext file? What does that look like?

Comment: Hi David, entity classes do exist, however, when I am adding new tables from the database, it's not adding any new file for those specific tables. Yes, there is a DbContext file, project is funcitional @DavidG.

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the issue raised, I conducted tests and found that if an entity class has been added to edmx, but the previous edmx is updated to add another entity class, the following situation will occur:

Entities in Diagram can be added normally, but entities in Solution Explorer are not generated normally. For example, my edmx has three entity classes: Person, Class, and Room. At this time, I added a new Activity table in the database and updated it in edmx, but the following situation occurred: Activity does not appear in Solution Explorer

[image]

[image]

But at this time, you only need to right-click the project, click Rebuild, and Activity will appear in Solution Explorer.

[image]

[image]